# How to implement a new BRDF in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osl

I want to implement a new BRDF in Cycles.

I've already tried to code an OSL node but I couldn't because the way that BRDF closures are implemented in OSL seem to only permit BRDF closure composition.

I would like to now the standard (simplest) protocole to add a new BRDF closure in Cycles.
I've already had my own blender build so I can modify the source code if there isn't another solution.

Edit : Or maybe, somebody eventually know where I can ask to get the answer ?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Note that [questions about modifying the source aren't considered on topic here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/225/599). If you are looking for an OSL answer that's great, but for source code questions you might try asking around on [IRC and such](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact) where you are more likely to find a developer :)

Comment: So I don't know yet if my question is out of the scope ! 
I'll try on IRC or mailing list.
Thanks for your answers :-)

Comment: @gandalf3 I think this question is within this site's scope, and I need an answer too. ;-<